# JQuery nested ajax passes parameters null to mvc controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, controller

I do nested ajax with JQuery, with interactions to MVC controller. First ajax is a POST request and I can get parameters truly in it, but in the second ajax GET request always passes parameters null to controller action. My codes:

JQuery:

```
`$(document).delegate('.xxx', 'click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
    var vid = $(this).parent().attr('data-vid');
    var pid = $(this).parent().attr('data-pid');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/ProArea/Product/ymethod/',
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "img_id": +id ,"pid":+pid,"vid":+vid}),
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
            alert(obj.varID + ', vid:' + obj.proID);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/ProArea/Product/xmethod/',
                async: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "html",
                data: { "vid": obj.varID, "pid": obj.proID }, 
                processData: false,
                success: function (d) {

                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("hata");
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});`
```

Controller:

```
 `public ActionResult xmethod(int vid,int pid)
        {
            ProRep pr = new ProRep();
            List<ProImage> pi = new List<ProImage>();
            pi = pr.somemethod(vid,pid);
            return PartialView("zmethod", pi);
        }`
```

In alert statement I can get the parameters but the controller call fails with null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Hikarunomemory I already tried JSON.stringify but it is not working. Only in the get ajax statement, parameters are actually not null but while passing to Mvc controller action they all null.

Comment: I'm relatively sure you cant use `processData: false` when you want to use a json object as data with `type: 'GET'`. That would prevent your data to get processed and appended to your url in the needed format.

Comment: As @Lapskaus said above, comment `processData: false` out or set it to `true`

Comment: @Lapskaus I just tried. Either removing processData: false or setting processData: true not worked

Comment: Any error message in console? I have tried in my project and it worked.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory If I make parameter types nullable int or string, I see that controller parameters are null. If I make parameter types normal int in controller action, I get 500 internal server error.

Comment: Can you check the value of `obj.varID` since your alert is showing `proID`  twice. `alert(obj.proID + ', vid:' + obj.proID);`

Comment: @Hikarunomemory they are working fine I can get the values

Comment: Don't know why but changing `data: { "vid": obj.varID, "pid": obj.proID }` to `data: { 'vid': +obj.varID, 'pid': +obj.proID }` worked. Also processData: needs to be true. Thanks for helping! @Lapskaus